# Mini usb 2.0 microphone not detected

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, microphone

I googled but didnt find an answer. I bought usb microphone like this:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/USB-2-0-Mini-Mikrofon-Stecker-f-r-Windows-PC-Mac-Linux-Raspberry-Pi-Mikrophon/112352215940?pageci=4c6236af-efda-43a9-8cc1-493daed3fb90

I tried both on rpi 4 and rpi 3 b+ but I can get it to list of recording devices with arecord -l.

I've also think that it isn't in list of usb devices using lsusb.

Do you have any idea how should I proceed?

Comment: see if it is detected on a PC

Comment: Yes, if an eBay guy says his goody works for a long list of computers including Arduino, Windows, Linux, and .... Rpi, with Rpi at the very end of the list, then there is a little bit of more than 1% chance that his thing doe NOT work with Rpi. And even if something works with Rpi3 or Win7, it wont' work with Rpi4 or Win10, ... :(